# inserting into a XML file by Javascript, Jquery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, insert

Is there any way to insert some data into XML file??
For example, if there is a XML code like this
`<charlist> 
<list> 
<title>gb</title> 
<chr>Goodbye</chr>` 
`` `</list> 
<list> 
<title>ttyl</title> 
<chr>talk to you later</chr> `` 
`</list> 
</charlist>`
How can i insert more data like "" into XML file.
I used "append" to add more data into a XML file, but it did not work.
Do I need to use Ajax or the others???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't without using a server side language - you can append it in memory, but you'd have to use something else to store it forever ;)

**note** You *could* use HTML5 `LocalStorage()`, but this probably isn't what you are looking for :(